# How to add datetime in a python dictionary

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to add a datetime inside python dictionary. As for now, when I append it, the output of the dictionary is split. How do I make it into timestamp instead? Current code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
date = datetime.now()
dict = {"date":[]}
dict["date"].append(date)
```

Current Output:

```
{'date': [datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 17, 3, 33, 23, 927394)]}
```

Expected Output:

```
 2021-05-17 13:25:37.860703
```

Comment: Don't overwrite the built-in `dict` - use another variable name for your dictionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `str(datetime)` to convert it to a string.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
date = datetime.now()
dict = {"date":[]}
dict["date"].append(str(date))
```

Output:

```
{'date': ['2021-05-17 09:07:31.391076']}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace line 4 with following and print dict in terminal.

```
dict["date"].append(date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"))
```